# Why no capacity in ConcurrentQueue?

Tags: .net

Why doesn't `ConcurrentQueue` have a `capacity` like its non-concurrent cousin?
There isn't a mentioning of a default capacity either.

Does the "missing" capacity impact performance compared to the non-concurrent version where the implementer can provide a qualified guess of the typical size of the queue?

Comment: Because implementation doesn't need capacity? Concurrent and non-concurrent data structures has different implementations.

Comment: Maybe check [this post](http://www.codethinked.com/net-40-and-system_collections_concurrent_concurrentqueue) - the way it's implemented is completely different to the non-concurrent one which just has a single internal array. As such, telling it how many items you're going to add first and then adding them or not giving that information and just adding the items would result in exactly the same number of allocations.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

ConcurrentQueue is implemented using lock free techniques. It is based on "Linked list". Capacity doesn't makes sense in Linked list so it doesn't expose the capacity.

Adding elements to the LinkedList is dirt cheap, it doesn't need to resize the array. It is just modifying the Tail pointer(reference). If the implementation uses array, then resizing the array is expensive, so pre allocating the array will improve performance significantly when you enqueue many elements.

Other non concurrent implementations of the `Queue` (`System.Collections.Generic.Queue<T>` and `System.Collections.Queue`) are array based. So it makes sense to pre allocate the array with given capacity in order to avoid resizing the array often and thus it exposes a Capacity property.

Comment: @Downvoter Explaining what's wrong with the answer will be appreciated.

Comment: I truly hate random @downvoters. If there's something wrong, say it. Don't hit and run.

Comment: Indeed. We are adults. We won't down-vote you for down-voting us... @downvoters

Comment: Downvote has been removed now. I assume my answer is correct ;P

Comment: @SriramSakthivel Nothing wrong with the answer IMO. Additionally, a draw back of the ConcurrentQueue might be the dequeuing which can suffer from cache misses due to the underlying linked list.